# How to find different strings on the same line using grep

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I'm trying to find all lines within a text file that contain a first string, something like `|Kittens|Color|`. And then I want the search to skip over what's in the next set of `||` to search for the second string like `|Location|`.

Everything in the file is separated by the pipe `|` symbols. In other words I want all the lines in the text file that contain Kittens, Color, and Location when they are in the file as such:

```
12321415|Kittens|Color|Gender|Location|
```

Comment: something like (off the top of my head) `grep Kittens foo.txt|grep Gender | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" }; { print $5 }'`

Comment: If none of the proposed answers satisfy your requirements, please consider adding more details to your question, such as maybe a few more examples, so we can see which parts are fixed, and which should be parametrized. Are the fields always 2, 3, and 5? Is the order of the words significant? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The fields will always be 2,3, and 5. I want grep to search for the specific strings I'm looking for that are in these fields regardless of what is in any of the other fields. So I may want |Kittens| (which may be on several lines of the text file) and there may be several locations by I want a specific |Location| regardless of what is in the |Gender| field.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is to use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F"|" '$2=="Kittens" && $3=="Color" && $5=="Location"' file
```

This sets the pipe `|` as field separator and, based on that, checks the values of the specific fields 2, 3 and 5. If all of them match with the given values, then the line is printed.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
12321415|Kittens|Color|Gender|Location|
12321415|Kittens|Color|Location|Blabla|
asdf|asdf|asdf|ads|asd|
```

And execute the awk:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2=="Kittens" && $3=="Color" && $5=="Location"' a
12321415|Kittens|Color|Gender|Location|
```

Answer (score 0):

To print out entire lines that match that information use something like:

```
awk -F'|' '$2=="Kittens" && $3=="Color" && $5=="Location"'
```

If you only want to print the fifth field then use:

```
awk -F'|' '($2=="Kittens" && $3=="Color" && $5=="Location"){print $5}'
```

Or, since that is not a particularly useful command and you might have meant that `Location` was a placeholder print the fifth field of every line that matches the first two specifications.

```
awk -F'|' '($2=="Kittens" && $3=="Color"){print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no mention of fixed fields, so I'm offering this alternative.

```
grep -E '\|Kittens\|Color|(.*\|)?Lovation\|' file
```

As you can see, this particular field separator is not a very happy one with (extended, as in `grep -E`) regular expressions.

If the order is completely free in the general case, a brute-force pipeline may be the easiest;

```
grep -F '|Kittens|' file |
grep -F '|Color|' |
grep -F '|Location|'
```

will find lines containing all three, in any order.